# Count users with same address and return them into blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I've got a "Patient" model which contains name, date of birth, address etc of each patient. I would like to group patients that have the same address, in order to detect the addresses that contain more people infected. So I've created a new model that only shows List Operations, and got this query inside it:

```
$this->crud->addClause('where', 'stato', '=','POSITIVE');
$this->crud->groupBy('address');
$this->crud->query->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ", ") as names, id as ids, COUNT(*) as count');
$this->crud->orderBy('count','desc');
```

Then, I set my columns as such:

```
protected function setupListOperation()
{
    $this->crud->addColumns([
    [
        'name'   => 'address',
        'label'  => 'Address',
        'orderable' => false,
    ],
    [
        'name'   => 'count',
        'label'  => 'Infected',
    ],
    [
        'name'   => 'names',
        'label'  => 'names',
        //'type'   => 'markdown',
        'orderable' => false,
    ]
]);
    $this->crud->enableDetailsRow();
    $this->crud->setDetailsRowView('vendor.backpack.crud.details_row.outbreaks');
}
```

This returns a list of addresses, with their counts, and a long string of names living at that address.
Example:

```
| Address           | Infected | Names                      |
|-------------------|----------|----------------------------|
| Address Street, 4 | 35       | Name1, Name2, Name3 etc... |
```

As setupListOperation() seems to be inconvenient to list long strings of names, I tought I'd make a custom details_row to list all patients living at each address.

```
<div class="m-t-10 m-b-10 p-l-10 p-r-10 p-t-10 p-b-10">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul>
        {{-- @foreach($entries as $entry) --}}
        <li>
        <a href="positivi/{{ $entry->id }}/show">
        {{ $entry->name }}</a>
        <small>({{ $entry->age }} years old)</small>
        </li>
        {{--@endforeach--}}
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it only gives me one name for address! I tried to pass the query variable "names", as well as trying to do a foreach loop inside the view, but none are working. What's the best way to list all patients living at the address, also linking their id through href?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to know how many people are infected in each address(location) so you can start by collecting the addresses of the infected people by:

```
$addresses = Patient::where('stato', 'POSITIVE')->pluck('address');
```

Then you can loop through the array to get the count and a list of the infected people:

```
foreach($addresses as $address)
{
   // count the infected people in a location
   $count = Patient::where('address', $address)->where('stato','POSITIVE')->count();
   // get a list of the infected patients on a location
   $infected = Patient::where('address', $address)->where('stato', 'POSITIVE');

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I'm using Backpack for Laravel, the ListOperation function already loops through the query, specifically I would like to get that data into the showDetailsRow view. Is it possible with Backpack or shall I overwrite the loop and make my own table?